# Natural deduction predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I'm trying to solve this simple natural deduction problem:

$$\{∀x~(p(x) \to q(a)), ∀y~\lnot q(y)\} \vdash_{\small ND} \lnot p(a)$$

I started out by stating the premisses and the assumption, which is $p(a)$.
I used $p(a)$ in the first premise with the (→ E) rule to get $q(a)$.
Here's the problem, i got a $q(a)$ and a $∀y~¬q(y)$ which turns into $¬q(b)$?
since i already turned x to a.

The question is, can i turn the y to a aswell? If so it should be pretty easy to prove this. Or am i just completely off track?

Comment: Yes, you can infer $\neg q(a)$ from $\forall{y}:\neg q(y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate a *universal* quantifier with any constant (whether you've used it before in the deduction or not). For '$\forall$' means *all*, doesn't it?! So if you are given '$\forall y\neg Q(y)$', then anything you take will satisfy the condition expressed by '$Q$' -- in particular, the thing dubbed '$a$'.

As a footnote, it is probably not a great idea to think in terms of 'turning $x$ into $a$' or the like: what exactly could that mean? You are, to use the standard jargon, *instantiating* the quantifier -- i.e. moving from a general claim (and it is the whole quantifier/variable apparatus $\forall x ... x ...$ which expresses the generality) to an instance of it. And you do that by-removing-the-initial-quantifier-and-*substituting*-a-name-for-the-variable(s)-that-it-binds, which is best thought of as a single operation.